# Cannot convert a complex hex code to emoji

Tags: javascript, unicode, hex, emoji

I am trying to convert a hex code to emoji. e.g. the emoji with hex U+1F64C on the page https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-1-emoticons.

I can either use `String.fromCharCode` or `String.fromCodePoint`.

I want to avoid using surrogate pairs because I'm writing a dynamic code where the emoji could be a simple hex like 2728 or a one like 1F601.

Can anyone help with the example given?

Answer (score 0):

Per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/fromcharcode), `String.fromCharCode` takes hex codes in UTF-16. So, to get U+1F64C, you'd need to use the UTF-16 representation of that character, . (You can use [Richard Ishida's conversion tool](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) to get the UTF-16 sequence or other representations.)